# Pass string parameter into assemble partial

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I'm trying to pass a string parameter into a partial

This is my call to my partial.

```
{{> loginButton hide-on-mobile}}
```

This is my partial

```
<a href="/login" class="login {{this}}">Log in</a>
```

For some reason the value isn't being displayed. What am I doing wrong as it's driving me mad!!

**Update**

As suggested below by harco gijsbers, I needed to pass through an object not a string.

I did it in the following way using the parseJSON helper

```
{{#parseJSON '{"extraClass": "hide-on-mobile"}'}}
    {{> loginButton }}
{{/parseJSON}}
```

Comment: Is `parseJSON` a built-in function? If not, how can I enable it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is "hide-on-mobile" is not an object. You cannot pass strings directly to an partial. You will need an object. Maybe the example below will help.

With this object:

```
loginBtn = {
      label: "log in",
      href: "/login",
      extraCSS: "hide-on-mobile"
    }
```

And this partial:

```
<a href="{{href}}" class="login {{extraCSS}}">{{label}}</a>
```

The result will be

```
<a href="/login" class="login hide-on-mobile">Log in</a>
```

When the partial is called like:

```
 {{> loginButton loginBtn}}
```